# SQL data analysis procedure

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to perform a procedure in **SQL** where I have a table for e.g:

**BEFORE**

#### RECORD |  SETDATE  |  A  | B |  C |  D  | TOTAL | COLUMNID

BAD  |   20180320 |   0 |  6 |  3  | 0  | 9

BAV |  20180320|  0 |  0 | 1 |  0 |  1

I want to analyse each row and perform operations based on the entries in columns.  so for record 'BAD' i want to check the values on each column.  in this case col A = 0 therefore move to next column.  So for column B = 6, i need to create (INSERT) a new row (there splitting the original row) so the new row inserted will be:

RECORD | SETDATE   | A  | B  | C   |D |  TOTAL  |COLUMNID

BAD   |  20180320  | 0  | 6 |  0  | 0 |  9  |    B

going this way the end result will be per below:

**END RESULT**

#### RECORD | SETDATE   | A  | B  | C   |D |  TOTAL  |COLUMNID

BAD    | 20180320 |  0 |  6 |  0 |  0 |  9     | B

BAD    | 20180320 |  0 |  0 |  3 |  0 |  3     | C

BAV    | 20180320 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  1     | C

psedocode:

```
for rows = 1 to x
   x = #rows in table
 set rows = 1

    for col = 1 to Ubound(col)
        if val <> 0 then 
           INSERT NEW ROW ( ROW with column entries set to zero expect populated 
                    row) AND columnid = non-zero row.

        else
        end if
    next col

next row
end
```

delete original row --as row split into two in this case.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s i am using mssql, i'm a novice at it but the suggestion below as solve my problem.

Comment: First lesson: the **official** product name is **SQL Server** (not "mssql", or "ms-sql" or anything like that). You should use that official name when referring to this product - and don't tag with `mysql` - that's s **different** RDBMS - not SQL Server .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead going into loop if your columns are fixed Like A,B,C & D then you can
do some extra coding below mentioned

```
INSERT INTO New_Row(RECORD,SETDATE,A,B,C,D,TOTAL,COLUMNID)
SELECT RECORD,SETDATE,A,0,0,0,A,'A'
FROM Your_Table
WHERE A<>0

INSERT INTO New_Row(RECORD,SETDATE,A,B,C,D,TOTAL,COLUMNID)
SELECT RECORD,SETDATE,0,B,0,0,B,'B'
FROM Your_Table
WHERE B<>0

INSERT INTO New_Row(RECORD,SETDATE,A,B,C,D,TOTAL,COLUMNID)
SELECT RECORD,SETDATE,0,0,C,0,C,'C'
FROM Your_Table
WHERE C<>0

INSERT INTO New_Row(RECORD,SETDATE,A,B,C,D,TOTAL,COLUMNID)
SELECT RECORD,SETDATE,0,0,0,D,D,'D'
FROM Your_Table
WHERE D<>0
```

Comment: hey thanks shiv for the suggestions, this is solving what i am trying to achieve many thanks.